# Node mustache rendering server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mustache

I'm trying to create a simple application to compile mustache templates into static pages server side, here's what I've got so far:

```
var view = {

    title: "Joe",
    calc: function () {

        return 2+4;
    }

};

var mustache = require("mustache");
var template = require("./home.template");

var output = mustache.to_html(template, view);

console.log(output);
```

And my template looks like:

```
{{title}} spend {{calc}}
```

Any suggestions as to what is causing this to fail?

Here is the complete error message:

```
home.template:1
} spend {{calc}}
        ^

module.js:437
  var compiledWrapper = runInThisContext(wrapper, filename, true);
                        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (module.js:437:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/MorehouseJ09/Documents/production_development/mustache/current/compiler.js:12:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: What's the error message? You've written a statement.

Comment: Hmm, Its not doing what I want. What does the compiled wrapper mean? I'm trying to output html to the terminal

Comment: What does it output? That statement literally?

Comment: Just updated the error message ... thanks for any help

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mustache. Are you sure that you can provide function values to it?

Comment: yes, if i declare the template in the same file, as a string, it will compile fine

Answer (score 2):

Use `fs.readFile()` to read your template in as a string. Require won't work unless it's requiring javascript code, not mustache code.

http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_encoding_callback

**Edit**
See if this works...

```
var mustache = require("mustache");
var fs = require("fs");

var view = {

    title: "Joe",
    calc: function () {

        return 2+4;
    }

};

fs.readFile('./home.template', 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var output = mustache.to_html(data, view);
  console.log(output);
});
```

Comment: So, in OP's case `{{title}} spend {{calc}}` is interpreted as JavaScript code? That would make sense I guess. `{{title}}` can be interpreted as an identifier inside a block statement inside a block statement, etc.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what's going on as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hey, thanks but I'm still getting problems, I'll upload my code to this answer

Comment: You have to specify the encoding, I didn't do that at first, sorry

Comment: Code has been updated... you might also consider using [expressjs](http://expressjs.com)